# GtkCellRenderer g_object_set crush if multiple columns defined

Tags: gtk3

I want to set style to combobox item. Tried to use css - not working. 
So I tried to set properties directly via g_object_set.
In case of object **gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);** all goes fine and styles applied. But if **gtk_list_store_new(2, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING);** app crushes on g_object_set.

Code:

```
  GError * error =0;
    GtkComboBox* cb = GTK_COMBO_BOX(widget);
     // GtkListStore *store = gtk_list_store_new(2, GDK_TYPE_PIXBUF, G_TYPE_STRING);
     GtkListStore *store = gtk_list_store_new(2, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING);
    GtkTreeIter iter;

    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(GTK_LIST_STORE(store), &iter, -1, 0, "Netherlands",1, "Netherlands", -1);
    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(GTK_LIST_STORE(store), &iter, -1, 0, "Japan",1, "Netherlands", -1);
    gtk_combo_box_set_model(cb, GTK_LIST_STORE(store));

    GtkCellRendererText* cell = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
    gtk_cell_layout_pack_start(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(cb), cell, TRUE);
    gtk_cell_layout_set_attributes(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(cb), cell, "text", 0, NULL);

    GtkCellRendererText* cell2 = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
    gtk_cell_layout_pack_start(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(cb), cell2, TRUE);
    gtk_cell_layout_set_attributes(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(cb), cell2, "text",1, NULL);

    g_object_set(cell, "font", "Proxima Nova Rg 15");
    g_object_set(cell, "foreground", "#a5adbe");
    g_object_set(cell, "background", "#ffffff");
    g_object_unref(store);
```

Stack trace:

```
   strstr()
   ?? ()
   g_object_set_valist()
   g_object_set
```

Code is executed on **realize** signal of combobox

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When I've found **cell-background** property in [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCellRenderer.html#GtkCellRenderer--cell-background), it became obvious that I am using wrong properties. But it will not work alone, you have to specify **cell-background-set" = TRUE** as I found [here](https://github.com/4179e1/misc/blob/0d6e019007ff1af3e5e8b262bcdd55b56de8cbff/treeview/cellrenderer/cellrenderer.c#L81). Now it completely works for me - backgrounds, fonts, all set as needed.

My working code:

```
G_MODULE_EXPORT void on_countries_show(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer user_data)
{

    GError * error =0;
    GtkComboBox* cb = GTK_COMBO_BOX(widget);
    GtkListStore *store = gtk_list_store_new(2, GDK_TYPE_PIXBUF, G_TYPE_STRING);
    GtkTreeIter iter;

    int h = gtk_widget_get_allocated_height(widget);
    h = 18;
    GdkPixbuf *nl = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale ("flags/NL.png", h, h, TRUE, &error);
    GdkPixbuf *jp = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale ("flags/JP.png", h, h, TRUE, &error);

    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(GTK_LIST_STORE(store), &iter, -1, 0, nl, 1, "Netherlands", -1);
    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(GTK_LIST_STORE(store), &iter, -1, 0, jp, 1, "Japan", -1);
    gtk_combo_box_set_model(cb, GTK_LIST_STORE(store));

    GtkCellRenderer* pb = gtk_cell_renderer_pixbuf_new();
    gtk_cell_layout_pack_start(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(cb), pb, TRUE);
    gtk_cell_layout_set_attributes(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(cb), pb, "pixbuf",0, NULL);

    GtkCellRenderer* cell = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
    gtk_cell_layout_pack_start(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(cb), cell, TRUE);
    gtk_cell_layout_set_attributes(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(cb), cell, "text", 1, NULL);

    g_object_set(pb,
               "cell-background", "white",
               "cell-background-set", TRUE,
               NULL);

     g_object_set(cell,
                    "font", "Proxima Nova Rg 15",
                    "background", "white",
                    "foreground", "#a5adbe",
                    "cell-background-set", TRUE,
                    NULL);

    g_object_unref(store);
}
```

If anybody will stuck like me - you are welcome ;-)